# How to iterate a big list to make it smaller for a REST call using Java streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have logic something like this to process in chunks.

```
List<String> bigList = getList(); // Returns a big list of 1000 recs
int startIndex=0;
boolean entireListNotProcessed=false;
while(entireListNotProcessed) {
   int endIndex = startIndex + 100;
   if(endIndex > myList.size()-1) {
      endIndex=myList.size()-1;
   }
   List<String> subList= bigList.subList(startIndex, endIndex);
   //call Rest API with subList and update entireListNotProcessed flag...
}
```

Is there a better way of doing this iteration using java streams?

Comment: "Returns a big list of 1000 recs" - 1000 elements is like nothing. Big would be in milions of elements.

Comment: Anyway, your solution looks fine to me.

Comment: Why don’t you use a straight-forward counting loop? `for(int startIndex = 0, endIndex, size = bigList.size(); startIndex < size; startIndex = endIndex) {  List<String> subList = bigList.subList(startIndex, endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + 100, size));  /* processing of subList */  }`. The `entireListNotProcessed` flag is obsolete.

Comment: I could do that. I'm just wondering if there is any better way than traditional for loops.

Answer (score 3):

You could use ListUtils from [apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/) to do the splitting for you (if you really need to since 1000 is not that muuch)

```
List<List<Integer>> output = ListUtils.partition(largeList, targetSize);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Guava's [Iterables.partition](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#partition-java.lang.Iterable-int-) or [Lists.partition](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html#partition-java.util.List-int-)

```
Lists.partition(bigList, 100).forEach(subList -> callRestApi(subList));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60225254/11733759), by creating range with stepping and then `subList`:

```java
int step = 100;
IntStream
  .iterate(0, o -> o < bigList.size(), o -> o + step)
  .mapToObj(i -> bigList.subList(i, Math.min(i + step, bigList.size()))
  .forEach(subList -> callRestApi(subList));
```

Or you can extract method:

```java
private static <T>  Stream<List<T>> partition(List<T> list, int step) {
    return IntStream
        .iterate(0, o -> o < list.size(), o -> o + step)
        .mapToObj(i -> list
            .subList(i, Math.min(i + step, list.size()))
        );
}
```

and then

```
partition(bigList, 100).forEach(subList -> callRestApi(subList));
```

Comment: Instead of `(i + step >= bigList.size()) ? bigList.size() : i + step`, I’d use `Math.min(i + step, bigList.size())`.

Answer (score 0):

You can batch your processing into chucks of a fixed size (or more advance dynamically computed batch size).

```
 final List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,); // any range of items.
    final int batchSize = 3;
    final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    final Collection<List<Integer>> result = numbers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / batchSize))
        .values();
```

You have now a collection of `List` of `N` element each **(N=3)**

Comment: A good proof that “using the Stream API” does not imply “better”.

Comment: Would be happy to have some insights

Comment: a) an external counter is defeating the intent of the Stream API, as it makes the code rely on the processing order, which is not guaranteed. b) `AtomicInteger` adds the expenses of thread safe updates, while the code is not thread safe due to the dependency on the processing order mentioned in *a*. c) `subList` is a copying free operation, as it creates a view to a part of the original `List`. In contrast, your solution creates new lists containing all elements, plus an additional `HashMap` holding all of them (all lists being fully materialized in memory even before the processing starts).